# Is there a way to fix/repair a damaged storage device?

Tags: data-loss, data-corruption

Say I mistakenly take out an SD Card or External HDD while it is being written to, and it needs to be repaired.

Similar to Windows, when a damaged/slightly corrupted storage device is inserted, it prompts you to fix the device. **Does such a feature exist on Ubuntu/Linux?** It can be a command, anything.

Comment: Is the `fsck` command what you're after?

Comment: @Android Dev - I honestly don't know much about fiddling with file system commands on Linux, but I'll look more into fsck right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach your device to Ubuntu, then use:

```
sudo parted -l /dev/sdx
```

Change `x` with your device id, e.g: `/dev/sdc`. you can use `parted -l` to get a list of all drives/partitions then detect which on is your desired one based on their size.

This command will tell you what partitions with which file systems are living on your device, for example:

```
 1      1049kB  8186MB  8185MB  primary   ext4
```

As you can see my drive has "one" partition which has been formated with "ext4".

so I can run:

```
sudo fsck.ext4 /dev/sdc1
```

to check and fix inconsistency in this drive, if file system was something like "ext2" I could run:

```
sudo fsck.ext2 /dev/sdc1
```

There are a lot of other stuff for other file systems:

```
fsck.btrfs     fsck.ext3      fsck.fat       fsck.nfs       fsck.xfs       
fsck.cramfs    fsck.ext4      fsck.minix     fsck.reiserfs  
fsck.ext2      fsck.ext4dev   fsck.msdos     fsck.vfat
```

Pay attention to "1" in "sdc1", "sdc" is my drive and "sdc1" is my only partition in that drive.

If your file system is NTFS I strongly suggest you to connect your device to a windows and run check disk on windows.

Comment: Thanks! I should have had this in mind earlier. (I'd umount the device first, though.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are such tools in Ubuntu at least for some file systems, for example for ext file systems, `e2fsck` for ext file systems, `ext2`, `ext3`, `ext4`.

But if there is a Microsoft file system, it is best to use a Microsoft tool to repair it, particularly for `NTFS`, while there is a fairly good tool in Ubuntu for the `FAT32` file system, `dosfsck` alias `fsck.fat`, that you install with

```
sudo apt-get install dosfstools
```

See also this link: [Repair the partition table and file system of a pendrive](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986)